# Blogger Notable Template - Next Article and Previous Article Buttons missing

Tags: pagination, blogger

In one of the newer Google blogger templates, `Notable,` when you're viewing a blog post the `Next Article` and `Previous Article` buttons are not present.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852609/blogger-notable-template-post-pagination-fix-or-replacement) explained how to add pagination buttons onto the blog homepage to view the next listing of articles and the previous listing of articles but didn't get into adding similar buttons on a blog post to view the next and previous article.

[Example of Main Blog Page with Pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csJmc.jpg)

[Example of Blog Article needing Pagination (Highlighted in Pink)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siSL8.jpg)

Any idea how to add this functionality? I'm just looking to add 'Previous Article' and 'Next Article' buttons to individual blog posts.

**EDIT** Updated images for hopefully more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found the answer. Just needed to add

```
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
          <b:include cond='data:newerPageUrl' name='previousPageLink'/>
          <b:include cond='data:olderPageUrl' name='nextPageLink'/>
        </b:if>
```

Within this code

```
      <div class='post-bottom'>
        <div class='post-footer'>
          <!-- Footer bylines -->
          <b:include name='footerBylines'/>
        </div>
          <b:include cond='data:view.isSingleItem and data:widget.type == &quot;Blog&quot;' data='{ shareButtonClass: &quot;post-share-buttons-bottom&quot;, overridden: true }' name='maybeAddShareButtons'/>
          <b:include cond='data:view.isMultipleItems or data:widget.type == &quot;PopularPosts&quot;' data='post' name='postJumpLink'/>
      </div>
```

Like so

```
      <div class='post-bottom'>
        <div class='post-footer'>
          <!-- Footer bylines -->
          <b:include name='footerBylines'/>
        </div>
          <b:include cond='data:view.isSingleItem and data:widget.type == &quot;Blog&quot;' data='{ shareButtonClass: &quot;post-share-buttons-bottom&quot;, overridden: true }' name='maybeAddShareButtons'/>
          <b:include cond='data:view.isMultipleItems or data:widget.type == &quot;PopularPosts&quot;' data='post' name='postJumpLink'/>
          <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
            <b:include cond='data:newerPageUrl' name='previousPageLink'/>
            <b:include cond='data:olderPageUrl' name='nextPageLink'/>
          </b:if>
      </div>
```